# CWE based Test Suite for Javascript / Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, security

Is there a widely known test suite with testcases based on CWEs like the Juliet Test Suite for C/C++ from NIST but for **Javascript & Typescript**? I was not able to find a similar ready to use solution, only some specific plugins that support your own unit tests.

The purpose would be to evaluate the performance of different static code analysis tools.